# going two activities back in android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

In my application suppose I have 3 activities A,B,C.

In application from Activity A it goes to B and from B to C.

Now what I want is if user is at Activity C.

When it click button it should go to Activity B.I had achieved  this by calling `finish()`. But in Activity C I am getting response from Server. Now what I want is after getting response activity A has to be called.(without storing history of activity B in stack).  How to achieve this?

Comment: why don't you just start the activity A from activity C with an intent?

Comment: @fedorSmirnov then on click of back it will call again Activity C

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to destroy a specific Activity such as Activity B, you can use receiver for that.

```
// declare your receiver in ActivityB

private MyReceiver receiver;

// register your receiver in onCreate() to get broadcast
registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter("DESTROY"));

// customize BroadcastReceiver to your need   
class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals("DESTROY")) 
            finish();
    }
}
```

And in ActivityC, you can send a receiver to destroy ActivityB,

```
sendBrodcast(new Intent("DESTROY");
```

ActivityB will get this broadcast and finish itself.

Answer (score 1):

Intent intent = new Intent(C.this,A.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |  Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);